# Create Subquery project from given path failed! Error: Entry file undefined for datasource not exist

Tags: docker

I tried to run my first [SubQuery](https://www.subquery.network/) project by following SubQuery Quick Start guide but ran into this error while trying to run the project with Docker. I just installed and started using Docker just now and have trouble understanding the framework behind it.

I ran the docker using:
`yarn start:docker`

But then received:

```
subquerygetstartedtutorial-postgres-1        | 2022-06-27 17:13:49.821 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
subquerygetstartedtutorial-subquery-node-1   | 2022-06-27T17:13:55.922Z <configure> ERROR Create Subquery project from given path failed! Error: Entry file undefined for datasource not exist
subquerygetstartedtutorial-subquery-node-1 exited with code 1
subquerygetstartedtutorial-subquery-node-1   | 2022-06-27T17:13:57.307Z <configure> ERROR Create Subquery project from given path failed! Error: Entry file undefined for datasource not exist
subquerygetstartedtutorial-subquery-node-1 exited with code 1
subquerygetstartedtutorial-subquery-node-1   | 2022-06-27T17:13:58.646Z <configure> ERROR Create Subquery project from given path failed! Error: Entry file undefined for datasource not exist
container for service "subquery-node" is unhealthy
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: Try going through the [quickstart](https://university.subquery.network/quickstart/quickstart.html) using npm instead of yarn.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `tsconfig.json` has this:

[image]

Now try running `yarn build` or `subql build` from your subquery project directory. This will create a build folder in your root which will be used as the data source as mentioned in your `project.yaml` file like this:

[image]

Now try to run `yarn start:docker`